# Tab links using only the page and app_id has stopped working, is there an alternative beyond querying Facebook each time?

Tags: facebook

A few days ago these type of links worked: http://www.facebook.com/pages/132456789?sk=app_132465798465 but now they give 404's.

The alternative is link to the namespace of the page like so: http://www.facebook.com/pages/foo/1456798324564?sk=app_134654689794 however to find out the link I'd need to ask Facebook for it, and it seem like since the namespace can change I can't just ask for it once.

Is there another way to use page and app id's to link to tabs without needing the roundtrip to Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that first format was ever used on Facebook, i'm surprised it worked.

As far as I can tell the 'name' part of a page URL is arbitrary, so just filling in something there will work, e.g.
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Tea/194040780316?sk=info

will also work as

http://www.facebook.com/pages/some_random_text/194040780316?sk=info

Comment: I'm pretty sure I figured out it existed just by looking at how Facebook was linking to itself at some point. I didn't realize that it was arbitrary, that helps a lot. Thanks. :)